# Django Query - How to use the objects.filter results

Tags: python, mysql, django

If I use the following code it works perfectly:

```
campaignnoquery = UserSelection.objects.filter(user=349).order_by('-campaignno')[:1]

for x in campaignnoquery:
    test2 = x.campaignno
```

However, when I try:

```
campaignnoquery = UserSelection.objects.filter(user=349).order_by('-campaignno')[:1]

test1 = campaignnoquery.campaignno
```

I get the following error:

```
 test1 = campaignnoquery.campaignno
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'campaignno'
```

I am sure it is something basic and I could just crack on with the one that worked but I am just intrigued on whats happening.

Many thanks in advance, Alan.

Comment: The `filter` method returns a `QuerySet`, which you need to iterate in order to get the `compaignno` attribute. That's why the snippet where you are iterating over `campaignnoquery` works. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: All I was trying to do was return the campaignno.  I just wondered if it could be done without the extra step of the iteration or if that is the way it should be done?   Many thanks for swift response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`campaignnoquery` is, as the error says, a `QuerySet` object (in this case it holds `UserSelection` instances).

Your error is treating it as an instance of a single `UserSelection` object.

Are you sure this `filter` will always return a single object? if so, you can use `get` instead.

If not, what are you expecting `campaignnoquery.campaignno` to return? (considering `campaignnoquery` is a **group** of `UserSelection` objects).

Comment: That makes complete sense.  Because I used the "[:1]" part I thought it would always just return a maximum of 1, maybe none.  But i think i can use the "try" method to capture that.  I will look to test out the get option, thank you.

Comment: @AlanTingey `[:1]` indeed makes sure that `campaignnoquery` will contain a single object, **but** it would still be contained in a `QuerySet`. Just like `'a string'` is not the same as `['a string']`.

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing the wrong object!

When looping through campaignnoquery, ***x*** becomes campaignnoquery[0], campaignnoquery[1], etc...

Try referencing it like this:

```
test1 = campaignnoquery[0].campaignno
```

Comment: Yes, that works and makes complete sense.  Can I tick two options as correct?

Comment: @AlanTingey You can accept 1 answer, but upvote as many as you like

Comment: @AlanTingey you should accept and upvote if it helped :)